# Access Environment variables on compilation step in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, environment-variables, angular-cli

Is there any way to access environment variable in angular 2 components when using `ng serve`?

E.g.:

```
API_URL=http://api.test.com ng serve
```

How can I access API_URL in Angular components?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI provides "environment" files just for that purpose. For development, put your configuration in the file:

```
src\environments.ts
```

For production, use the"

```
src\environments.prod.ts
```

When you build the application with:

```
ng build -prod
```

(or just ng build since -prod is the default)

Angular will use the environment.prod.ts file in place of the environment.ts file.

Comment: Thanks for reply Boyan! When I use environments.ts files, I should know values of environment variables beforehand to describe each of them for each environment, but the main purpose is that API_URL can be dynamically changed and how I can access it directly in components without adding new values for environments

Comment: What you are asking for can be done, but it gets more complex fast. Check out my other answer about providing configuration at run-time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077544/angular-2-and-team-city-production-environment-variables-best-practices/42078017#42078017