# Injecting environment variables Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Currently the environment.ts file contains only environment:true for production and false for dev. I have some more config level variables like cdn path, server path and few others(30 more) which change based on application ENV. How should i make them available to all the components and services and the value of variables should change when the --prod is passed during build time. Instead of manually changing it.

I am using Ng-Cli@1.3.0 for build

***EDIT:***
Is it safe to directly provide it in the environment file, is it available on client side for changing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Environment variables on compilation step in Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161059/access-environment-variables-on-compilation-step-in-angular-cli)

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: I am not sure to really understand your goal here. You want that, during execution of angular, change your environment variables ? Can you provide an precise example of what behavior you expect for your angular application ?

Comment: if it is that, the correct way to do that would my IMO to create an application (like a simple node express API) on same server, that your angular services will call, that will access the current Environment variables on your machine and serve the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

you an use environment

**src/environments/environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  server_url: 'https://api.exapmle/'
};
```

**src/environments/environment.ts (default)**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  server_url: 'https://api.dev.exapmle/'
};
```

change angular/cli file

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
```

you can access the values from every component, service

```
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment'



  api_url = environment.server_url;
```