# Include script tag conditionally in angular 4 app

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4.4.6 and have `<script>` tag outside my `app-root`. it looks like this

```
<script src="someUrlForQa"></script>
```

and i want to delete this one and include

```
<script src="someUrlForProd"></script>
```

when it will be on production.

What is the right way to do it? Maybe using `angular-cli.json` somehow?

Comment: This question on the CLI repo should help you. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4288

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using plain Javascript.

```
let el = document.createElement('script');

if(condition) {
   el.src = 'someUrl';
}
else {
   el.src = 'otherUrl';
}

document.head.append(el);
```

However, it's against the Angular style guide to interact directly with the DOM. If you do this in Angular, the 'Angular way' of creating this would be by injecting and using the `Renderer2` service:

```
constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

public someMethod() {
    let el = this._renderer.createElement('script');
    el.src = 'conditionalUrl';
    this._renderer.appendChild(el, this_renderer.selectRootElement('body'));
}
```

As far as *when* to do this in Angular, you could hijack the `APP_INITIALIZER` service and provide your own initialization code. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077544/angular-2-and-team-city-production-environment-variables)
for more information.